# NullPointerException during deployment of Spring application packaged as a JBoss service archive

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I have a JBoss service archive (SAR) that I'm deploying to JBoss 4.2.2.GA. This deploys correctly locally, but throws the following exception during deployment on another server also running JBoss 4.2.2.GA.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$TypeProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:239)
```

This is bubbling up from the following line of code in the application:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
```

Where the `Config` class is a `Java Config` to instantiate a single bean.

The libraries, e.g. `Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE`, are packaged with the `SAR` so I wouldn't think it's a library mismatch issue, but I may be wrong.

What might be the issue here?

**Edit 1: Complete Stack trace**

```
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: - nested throwable: (java.lang.NullPointerException)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:196)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:226)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.install(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.create(SARDeployer.java:249)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:969)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:818)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$TypeProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:239)
at org.springframework.core.$Proxy38.hashCode(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:273)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.hashCode(ResolvableType.java:779)
at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.getHash(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:214)
at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.getReference(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:246)
at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.get(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:226)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1154)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1133)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forTypes(ResolvableType.java:812)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:388)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:350)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getRequiredTypeInfo(GenericConversionService.java:266)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.addConverterFactory(GenericConversionService.java:103)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addScalarConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:79)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:63)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.<init>(DefaultConversionService.java:50)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.<init>(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:41)
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:41)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:112)
at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.getOrCreateEnvironment(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:177)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.<init>(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:66)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:61)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:82)
at com.company.GetDBInfo.<init>(GetDBInfo.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.instantiate(MBeanServerImpl.java:1233)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.instantiate(MBeanServerImpl.java:286)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.createMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:344)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.install(ServiceCreator.java:157)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.internalInstall(ServiceConfigurator.java:451)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:171)
... 81 more
```

**Edit 2: GetDBInfo class**

```
public class GetDBInfo extends ServiceMBeanSupport implements GetDBInfoMBean
{
    private DatabaseSource databaseSource;

    public GetDBInfo()
    {   
    // Choose the database source bean based on the property
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);  // Line 58, where exception originates per stack trace
    ApplicationContext dbCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dbConnectionProviderContext.xml");
    databaseSource = (DatabaseSource)ctx.getBean(DbConfig.getDbBeanName());

    // Do some work with databaseSource....
    }
}
```

It's referenced in other applications on the server, like this:

```
public static GetDBInfoMBean getDBInfoBean(){

    GetDBInfoMBean mbean = null; 
    try {

        ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("com.company:service=GetDBInfo");
        MBeanServer server = MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();

        mbean = (GetDBInfoMBean) MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(  server,
                                  objectName,
                                  com.company.GetDBInfoMBean.class,
                                  false);

    } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
        logger.error("GetDBInfoMBean error" , e);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        logger.error("GetDBInfoMBean error" , e);
    }

    return mbean;
}
```

Comment: Please, post the complete stack trace.

Comment: Added complete stack trace

Comment: Show the com.company.GetDBInfo class and where its being refered.

Comment: I added the class with constructor only, the class is pretty big and I don't think the rest is relevant because it's failing on the first line of code in the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved by switching from JavaConfig to an XML config.

Answer (score 0):

If you using both spring(3.xxx or older) and spring 4.xxx,you must remove older version